# sqlserver how to do a insert, but if it exists update instead maneuver?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

Read a few things online and here but am now confused.  What I want to do is a simple insert... but if the record already exists I want to update it instead, how is this best achieved in ms sqlserver?

Here is a simple example of the insert:

```
INSERT INTO AdvertiserCategoryJoin
                  (AdvertiserID, CategoryID)
VALUES     (502910, 2)
```

I was trying to use ON DUPLICATE KEY but sqlserver doesn't have an equivalent, which was annoying, so what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the IF..ELSE conditions.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdvertiserCategoryJoin WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE AdvertiserID = 502910) = 1 BEGIN
UPDATE AdvertiserCategoryJoin
SET CategoryID = 2
WHERE AdvertiserID = 502910
END ELSE BEGIN
INSERT INTO AdvertiserCategoryJoin
                  (AdvertiserID, CategoryID)
VALUES     (502910, 2)
END
```

But there are other ways to do this too, using EXCEPT or EXISTS. It is really up to you and what you find easier to write/maintain, and as always if you are using SQL 2008 and are up for a challenge, you can use the [MERGE](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm) command, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: I opted for this option which works, and I understand it :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have SQL2008 version, there´s a very good statement for that.
[MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

```
MERGE AdvertiserCategoryJoin AS target
USING (SELECT @AdvertiserID, @CategoryID) AS source (AdvertiserID, CategoryID)
ON (target.AdvertiserID = source.AdvertiserID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET CategoryID = source.CategoryID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (AdvertiserID, CategoryID)
    VALUES (source.AdvertiserID, source.CategoryID)
    OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;
```